# Global resources for additional cultures being ignored on ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

I have this ASP.NET web application that I am developing with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6.1. I make extensive use of local and global resources to localize my app into English (default), Spanish and Galician. On my development machine, which uses IIS Express, everything works fine. But when I publish the web app to our production server, which uses IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008, the Spanish global resources are ignored, and only the default English as well as Galician are used.

I am publishing the web app through the "file system" method of Web Publish. As far as I can see, no `.resx` files get deployed for global resources; instead, files named `App_GlobalResources.resources.dll` get deployed into the `bin`, `bin/es` and `bin/gl` folders. In addition, a `MyNamespace.resources.dll` file is deployed to `bin/es` but not `bin/gl`, which is very odd.

I must also say that I am switching cultures in my code by setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to a `CultureInfo` object based on either `en-GB`, `es-ES` or `gl-ES`.

I have tried naming the global resource files in my code by using neutral (for example, `gl`) and localised (for example, `gl-ES`) forms of the culture codes. This does not seem to make any difference. Also, local resource files are named by using neutral variants.

Any ideas why the Spanish global resources are being ignored? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming the resource files correctly should work e.g. Have you tried naming the files using the full culture specification e.g. `ResourceTexts.resx`, `ResourceTexts.es-ES.resx` and `ResourceTexts.gl-ES.resx`. After publishing, they should be available in the `App_GlobalResources` folder.

Comment: Do I need to use the culture suffix also for English, which is the default one? Usually I leave it as ResourceTexts.resx with no qualifier.

Comment: Also, shall I also name local resources with the full culture spec as you suggest for global resources?

Comment: I have just tried to do as you suggest and nothing changes. :-( Also, the `App_GlobalResources` folder does not exist on my server. As I explain in my OP, DLLs are deployed to subdirectories under `bin`.

Comment: Sorry for the error on the default one, it shouldn't have the culture suffix

Comment: Does your solution have the ASP.Net folder 'App_GlobalResources' folder in it?

Comment: Also review through debug if the culture info object you are passing for culture 'es-ES' is actually 'es-ES' when the program is running?

Comment: Right click on the resource file and view the properties then ensure the Build Action is set to Content to have them in the folder.

Comment: Or alternatively set the Build Action to 'Embedded Resource' to embed them into the dll.

Comment: Also ensure the 'es-ES' resource file has the correct values otherwise, it would default to english.

Comment: One of my global resource files had an incorrect build action. I fixed it and now everything seems to be working. Thank you for your help.